# android how to start the main activity when I am on another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am on `signin` activity and if the user click a button I want to start the main activity.
this is the mainfest for the main activity `welcome`

```
<activity
            android:name=".Welcome"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I tried like this

```
Intent welcomeIntent =new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        startActivity(welcomeIntent);
```

but i got a screen saying `complete acting using` with many choese , what is the solution pelase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your intent to directly launch your class

```
Intent welcomeIntent = new Intent(context, Welcome.class);
startActivity(welcomeIntent);
```

If you're in an activity replace `context` with `this`